# How can I write a method that adds items to a linked list and sorts them alphabetically?

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I think I have a good start but when I run a test program I get: SortedLinkedList@2a139a55
Does this mean there is something wrong with my toString() or something wrong with my add() method?

```
 public void add(String data) {
            StringNode current = head;
            StringNode newNode = new StringNode(data);

            if (head == null) {
                head = newNode;
            } // End if

            else {
                while (current != null) {
                    if (data.compareTo(current.data) < 0)
                        break;
                    previous = current;
                    current = current.getNext();

                } // End while
            } // End else with while

        }// End add
```

My toString() is in an inner class called StringNode:

```
public static class StringNode {
        private String data;
        private StringNode next;

        public StringNode(String newData) {
            data = newData;
            next = null;
        }

        public String getData() {
            return data;
        }

        public void setData(String newData) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public StringNode getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        public void setNext(StringNode nextNode) {
            this.next = next;
        }// End setNext

        public String toString() {

            return data;
        }// End toString

    }// EndStringNode class
```

Comment: Looks like something wrong with your `toString()`. Please provide the code.

Comment: Mind you, `add` doesn't look like it works either - you only use `data` in the `head == null` case.

Comment: The `toString()` of your Node class seems fine. You need to override the one of your `SortedLinkedList` class.

Comment: `SortedLinkedList@2a139a55` is the default output of `SortedLinkedList.toString()` - if you want something else, you will need to override that method.

Answer (score 3):

Aside from the handling the empty list correctly, you're not actually putting the new node into the list when you find a place for it.

Within the while loop, the if statement needs to also insert newNode into the list, but all you're doing is breaking out.

You also must handle corner cases correctly: when newNode should become the new head or when newNode becomes the new tail.